# Is the Google TV platform Free?

Tags: google-tv

I know you can use Android free but is it possible to do the same with Google TV?

Let's say I want to build a box myself and use Google TV, do I need to negotiate with Google?

Comment: You may not be able to get the full "Google TV" experience on your box, but there's no reason it cannot run Android.

Comment: Example: http://www.androidtapp.com/android-on-a-stick-get-android-on-any-tv-with-hdmi/

Comment: @Chahk wow that is cool. Was wondering how powerful that  could be, but I guess when you take the screen and battery off a phone, what's left is pretty tiny, and phones get more than enough power to both charge and run off a USB port, so this should be ok. Will keep an eye out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *Legal questions* (see: [help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 5):

From the [Developer's FAQ for Google TV](https://developers.google.com/tv/faq#downloadgoogletv):

> **Can I download Google TV? When will it be open sourced?**
>
> You can't download Google TV itself, but Google TV hardware
>   manufacturers provide over-the-air (OTA) updates. We are working hard
>   to open source the code for the Google TV project.

So, as it hasn't been open sourced (yet), and Google specifically say that you can't download it, it looks like you're going to have to negotiate directly with them.